# List of all possible orders of a set of items in python

Tags: python, math, automation

I have a set of 6 items, lets call them "1" to "6". What I want to do is create another list with all possible combinations (orders?) of these items. Means in every possible combination, all 6 items have to be included and there cant be duplicates. It may be a combination backwards, since its a different set of numbers.

Heres my idea:

```
import random

items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ListOfCombinations = []
while True:
    random.shuffle(items)
    print(items)
    string = " ".join(str(e) for e in items)
    if string not in ListOfCombinations:
        ListOfCombinations.append(string)
```

What I tried to do here is create a random order and add it into the second list if its not already inside. But I feel like there has to be a different way of doing and I probably did it wrong to. I'm a noob at python so help would be appreciated!

Comment: Combinations or permutations?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Check here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 18):

You are looking for `permutations()` from the `itertools` library.

```
from itertools import permutations

# this will create all permutations of [0,1,2]
list(permutations(range(3)))

# returns:
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: python can do that? well okay, thanks for that. How do I enter them into a second list?

Comment: it returns a list on its own.  You can just assign it to a new variable or you can extend a list that already exists.

Comment: list(map(list, permutations(your_list)))

Comment: The second of arg `permutations()` defaults to the length, so just `list(permutations(range(3)))` works